# In Sql Server create spider grid logic around a coordinate

Tags: sql-server, trigonometry

I have a table of locations with monetary values and lat/lngs in Sql Server. When I add a new location I want to calculate the largest sum product $ of locations values within a 200m radius using sql. The first circle would be the new location's lat/lng, but then I would like to move the circle around in 50m increments (up to 200m away), to find the max exposure circle. I think I would create a hexagonal grid. But I've been stuck on how to do this for a long time. My math skills are poor.

Once I got the hexagonal points I was going to adapt and feed them into this (I know there will be some inaccurcy):

```
Declare @Lat  float = 51.500709
Declare @Lng  float = -0.124646
Declare @LatM float = -50
Declare @LngM float = 0

Select OldLat = @Lat
      ,OldLng = @Lng
      ,NewLat = @Lat + @LatM/111111
      ,NewLng = @Lng + @LngM/(111111 * cos(radians(@Lat)) )
```

Comment: Semi-related have you looked at the native spatial data capabilities of mssql to do the actual "find points within 200m"?

Comment: Thank you. Yes I have, that part is very handy. I couldn't see anything obvious to help me with projecting a point though.

Comment: Yeah. Seems tricky given the toolset. But wondering out loud, given that you're missing out on a maximum solution anyways (case in point - consider a circle with radius 200 and three equidistant points on the edge; unless you find the center of that circle by chance, you'll miss at least one of the points), could a simplification be to use each of the points in your set as the center of a circle to consider? I haven't thought about it rigorously but that *is* a problem that is doable purely with the spatial capabilities in SQL.

Comment: Yes I think that is a good idea. I have heard of an algorithm where a circle in this case with a 200m radius is drawn around each location and where these circles intersect a circle is plotted and the exposure calculation is made. Supposed to be more rigorous. Would that make sense here?